# add item to array in loop by this array js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following method:

```js
var items = [1,2,3];
$.map(items, function (item) {
  if (item === 1) {
    items.push(4);
  }
  console.log(item);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and I expect in console 1,2,3,4, but see 1,2,3. I mean I want to see one extra loop item.

Can I resolve it somehow? And if yes, how can I resolve it?

Comment: you have log wrong array instead of `item` use this `console.log(items);` this will give expect output.

Comment: `.map()` stores the original length of the array before invoking the callback ([step 2](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.map)). By design, it won't continue into *new* elements added during iteration.

Comment: Agreed with @JonathanLonowski

Comment: `console.log(item);` needs to be `console.log(items);`. Seems TYPO mistake to me

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Maybe I can use something instead `.map()` for this?

Comment: For such a think why don't you use native JS script? Is as simple as that: `var newItems = items.map(
    function( item ) {
        if ( item === 1 ) {
            items.push(4);
        }

        return item;
    }
);`

And keep in mind, the native `map` function it returns a new array, not the same you used as input.

Comment: `map()` is a transformation of an array into an equivalent array with different values. If you need to add different logic to the array, you should use `forEach`. Or, in the jQuery case, `$.each()`. Or better, the plain `for` loop will work very well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterator methods, like `.map()` or `.forEach()`, will prevent visiting elements added during iteration by using only the original `length`.

To avoid that, you'll want to use a standard loop, such as [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) (with the [default array iterator](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-createarrayiterator) checking `length` as it progresses):

```js
var items = [1, 2, 3];

for (var item of items) {
  if (item === 1) {
    items.push(4);
  }
  
  console.log(item);
}
```

Though, other types of loops can be used to do the same.

Of course, beyond this current example, be careful that the loop doesn't become infinite from there always being new elements to iterate to next.

Comment: What a coincidence? I just posted an answer almost similar to yours.

Answer (score 1):

Yes certainly you can resolve it, but in your specific case, `items` is passed by value to your `map` function so that you won't accidentally alter the original variable. The purpose of `map` is not for what you are using, but for mapping by specific key for an object or associative array. You should fall back to for loop or some other method for getting your desired output.

```js
var items = [1, 2, 3];
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  const item = items[i];
  if (item === 1) {
    items.push(4);
  }
  console.log(item);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

use ***forIn*** instead of ***forOf***,  because sometime **forOf** give an error (maybe ***forOf*** not supported older version of js )..

```js
         var items = [1,2,3];
         var k;
         for (k in items){
           if(items[k] === 1){
            items.push(4);
            }
         }
         alert(items);
```

Comment: `for..of` loops are relatively new to the language (since 2015), but are [supported by all modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Browser_compatibility). Though, a basic `for` loop would be a better alternative. [With arrays, `for..in` loops behave different than is often expected.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)